# Should the Dropout vs. Recurrent Dropout Arguments Be the Same in Keras?

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network, dropout

I'm learning about recurrent neural networks right now, and am in chapter 6 of [Deep Learning with Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617294438) by Francois Chollet.

In the chapter it's discussing using dropout in recurrent layers.  I understand the logic behind having the inputs randomized the same way at each time step since RNN's are used to learn sequence data, but I'm having a difficult time parsing some of the finer details between the `dropout` and `recurrent dropout` arguments you can pass in.

Take this simple example:

```
keras.layers.GRU(32, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)
```

Whenever I see snippets like this on the internet both dropout arguments are usually set to the same value.  Is this a best habit or just convention?

I'm assuming the `dropout` argument is the fraction of inputs that will be zeroed out coming into the recurrent layer.  If that's the case, what's the difference between my example and something like this:

```
keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)
keras.layers.GRU(32, recurrent_dropout=0.2)
```

Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your two snippets are equivalent. It is just syntactic sugar.

Btw. be careful about using the recurrent dropout. It usually makes things worse.

Comment: Your second paragraph is misleading. If you want to give such advice, at least be more verbose: when does it work and when not, why, what are the alternatives, etc?